# swf file not working in mobile devices?

Tags: c#, html, flash, jquery-mobile

I have used swf file in my project. It works well on desktop, but not on mobile devices.

I have used this code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0"
    height="400" width="600" align="top">
    <param name="movie" value="xxx.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
       <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <embed src="xxx.swf" height="510" width="640" align="top"
        quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        wmode="transparent"/>
</object>
```

I have also tried to convert swf file into html5 for mobile devices, but it has not worked properly.

Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Many things dont support swf any more.

Comment: ok but I want to show the page in all devices.Any solution for this?

Comment: @BugFinder many things **do** support swf data. Just that Flash _plugin_ was fully discontinued on mobile **browsers** & some smart TVs (Samsung only?) by 2013.

Comment: @Abila did you try to view with a different browser? Try using Dolphin (Android) or even Puffin (iOS).